# Writing multiple JSON objects into one .json file

Tags: python, json

I'm writing a python script to run through a csv file and convert it into one .json file. That would mean the .json file would have multiple json objects inside it. I've got most of the script working but the part I am confused with (and I've looked online for a while now) is how multiple JSON objects should be stored in one .json file. Is it either of the ways below? :

```
{
    "index": {
        "_index": "jobs", 
        "_id": 119556, 
        "_type": "2014_jobs"
    },
    "index2": {
        "_index": "jobs", 
        "_id": 119700, 
        "_type": "2014_jobs"
    },
    "index3": {
        "_index": "jobs", 
        "_id": 118701, 
        "_type": "2014_jobs"
    },           
}
```

or

```
{"index": {"_index": "jobs", "_id": 119556, "_type": "2014_jobs"}}
{"index2": {"_index": "jobs", "_id": 119700, "_type": "2014_jobs"}}
{"index3": {"_index": "jobs", "_id": 118701, "_type": "2014_jobs"}}
```

Comment: For more context, I'm writing to script to get data to run elasticsearch on it but the data isn't being accepted and the error says its due to the JSON formatting

Comment: put all json objects in a list

Comment: so after generating the complete list add it like json.dump(list, jsonfile)?

Comment: Hey hasson, thanks for your help! I managed to get the script to generate the objects the way I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks pritty close to the solution. May you should use a list:

```
{
 "data":[
    {
        "_index": "jobs", 
        "_id": 119556, 
        "_type": "2014_jobs"
    },
    {
        "_index": "jobs", 
        "_id": 119700, 
        "_type": "2014_jobs"
    },
    {
        "_index": "jobs", 
        "_id": 118701, 
        "_type": "2014_jobs"
    }]           
}
```

This would be my solution. Hope it helped

Comment: I realized I needed to submit multiple documents anyway but thanks!